# Using Device to authenticate a HTTP request

Tags: android, ruby, http, authentication, devise

I'm trying to authenticate a HTTP request using a token sent by an Android application, but I have no idea how to do this.

To get this token I must to send an user a password, to my ruby application that returns the token, but I want to know how to verify all requests from my android application using this token.

I know the "before_filter" on ruby, but I think that it could have problems with my first authentication, because I have to login with the user and password just once, but every time with the token.

If you can indicate any links or some pieces of code ...

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Would you pass this token back as a cookie or an http request header?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After successful log-in you should save Token in Constants and should send this token with each HTTP request.Server will verify user with access token and return result.